# How to multiply each element in an array with a different number (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var numbers = [3, 6 ,2, 7];
```

I want to multiply each number in `array` with `numbers` without repetition of numbers from `numbers`

Comment: how to determine the number to be multiplied with... is there a logic

Comment: The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function will help.

Comment: Surely you tried something first!

Comment: random or fixed number per index is ok

Comment: @technophobia -  i can only multiply them with one number

Comment: @Xufox - I'll look into that,tnx. most of the results i get when searching is by multiplying them to only one number for all elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed number for all index**

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];

array.map(
  function(n){
    return (n* number to be multiplied);
  }
);
```

**Different number for each index**

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3], numberToBeMultiplied = [1,3,5,7];

   array.map(
     function(n, i){
        return n * numberToBeMultiplied[i];
     });
```

You can also `push` the returning elements in an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, what I get you may want to do something like this.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4]
var array2 = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var randomMultiplier = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //Return a random number between 1 and 10
  array2.push(array[i] * randomMultiplier);
  $('#multiplied-list').append('<li>'+array[i] * randomMultiplier+'</li>')
}
console.log(array2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="multiplied-list"></ul>
```